# How to fix the xgboost import error in MacOs?

Tags: python, conda, xgboost

I had the xgboost library installed on my mac, but suddenly I get the python error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xgboost'`

That's what I executed:

- `pip install xgboost`
- `conda install xgboost`
- `pip3 install xgboost`
- `sudo pip3 install xgboost`

However, I always get the following error:

[image]

Could you give me a hand?

Thank you very much

Comment: I just saw the screenshot, you might have to reset your base environment, and possibly reinstall Conda just to be safe. Don't use pip inside of a Conda environment without taking the proper precautions (see https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/), and above all don't use the base environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have package manager Anaconda use:

```
conda install -c conda-forge xgboost
```

Or:

```
$ brew install gcc@5
$ pip install xgboost
```

If it's already installed, try:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Or:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install xgboost
```

Or:

If you were using pip, try to use pip3 or pip2

```
pip2 install xgboost
pip3 install xgboost
```

Here is your issue:
https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/3194

Briefly:
Download gboost from:

https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/files/1851733/xgboost-0.7.post5.tar.gz

then run:

```
pip3 install xgboost-0.7.post5.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mahsa Hassankashi, i solved the problem with the 'conda install -c conda-forge xgboost'

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get any version of XGBoost to work on my Mac even with the above, so I wanted to share that it works on an AWS EC2 **Linux** instance (https://aws.amazon.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed below packages on your mac:

```
brew install cmake
brew install gcc
brew install libomp
brew install openblas
```

Use below on Mac M1:

```
arch -arm64 brew install cmake
arch -arm64 brew install gcc
arch -arm64 brew install libomp
arch -arm64 brew install openblas
```

And also make sure you exported this before running pip install on your terminal:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openblas/lib/pkgconfig"
pip install xgboost
```